# What does PHP's socket_recv MSG_PEEK flag mean?

Tags: php, sockets

http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php

What is the purpose of MSG_PEEK and can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual says:

> Receive data from the beginning of the receive queue without removing it from the queue.

So, you can read that data again and again. This might be useful if several independent components should the read the same data from socket. Without this flag, the data will flushed from socket after your read it once

Comment: So if I did msg_peek to receive some data and then did a normal read would a subsequent call with msg_peek read new data?

For example if the buffer contains "this is a message"

and I peek 4 bytes and see "this"
then i read 4 bytes normally.
If i peek another 4 bytes will i get " is " ?

Comment: Yes. Btw, why not trying it?

Comment: @hek2mgl - Shouldn't the answer be No? If you use `MSG_PEEK` and read 4 bytes of data from a socket and you have `This is a message` on the wire you will always get `This` even in subsequent calls with the `MSG_PEEK` flag set (as long as you haven't done a normal read operation and therefore removed the data from the buffer).

Comment: @KristerAndersson Maybe I misunderstood the comment, but he wrote, *then I read 4 bytes normally* ... Anyway, correct is it like I wrote in the answer